# StatusStrip over form BackgroundImage

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a background image as stretch layout mode. When I place a StatusStrip on my form, it covers the bottom of the form's background image.

How I can set the bottom of the form's background image stretch area to the top of the StatusStrip?

Comment: Why don't you put a `Panel` (or some other container) with required background image instead of putting it on the form directly?

Comment: Or just draw it yourself, override OnPaintbackground().

Comment: I see you haven't changed any thing, did you solve your problem ? if you did then answer your question, if not edit it .

Answer (score -1):

I think the only correct workaround is what [Dmitry Bychenko mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707057/statusstrip-over-form-backgroundimage/27751889#comment43826226_27707057):

> Why don't you put a Panel (or some other container) with required background image instead of putting it on the form directly?

However I ended to edit the image and trim my form size (adequate for me), so that the StatusStrip covered the unused space below the image.